# Coloring a repetitive object using a color array

Tags: arrays, object, colors, processing

I am working on a project for university. I have only recently started learning to code and would really appreciate any help I can get. I am using processing and have imported the following libraries: xlsReader & ControlP5. I have created an object that is drawn 7 times.

My first attempt to color the objects using 7 specific colors for the 7 repetitive objects can be seen in the code below. I am still trying to figure this out but at the moment my objects are only reading the last color of the array. If anyone can please give me some advice or offer a different solution than using an array, I would be so grateful.

A piece of my coding is as follow:

```
if (showData == true) {
  for (int row = 0; row < 6; row++) {

    xPinBusiness = reader.getInt(row+1, col);

    int xPin1 = int(map(xPinBusiness, 0, 3000, amountsStart, amountsEnd));          

    color[] myColors = new color[7];
      myColors[0] = color(208, 102, 155);
      myColors[1] = color(64, 161, 177);
      myColors[2] = color(99, 153, 98);
      myColors[3] = color(101, 102, 156);  
      myColors[4] = color(255, 204, 87);
      myColors[5] = color(255, 154, 22);
      myColors[6] = color(255, 53, 41);    


for (int colorRange = 0; colorRange < myColors.length; colorRange+=1){

    pin1.display(myColors[colorRange], xPin1, 295, 20);


    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `draw()` function goes through your `for loop` and then uses the end result for the value of `color`, which is the last value in your array, as the `color` that it passes into your function. In other words, your GUI is basically *frozen* or *locked* while the `for loop` runs so the intermediate values, even though they are considered inside the loop, don't have any affect on whatever is being drawn on the screen.

Simplify your `draw()` function by removing the loop and doing something like the example code below (I used your array of `colors` for this example):

```
int colorCounter;

void setup()
{
  // slowed down the frameRate so you can see the effect of colors changing.
  frameRate(5);
  colorCounter = 0;
}

void draw()
{
  color[] myColors = new color[7];
  myColors[0] = color(208, 102, 155);
  myColors[1] = color(64, 161, 177);
  myColors[2] = color(99, 153, 98);
  myColors[3] = color(101, 102, 156);  
  myColors[4] = color(255, 204, 87);
  myColors[5] = color(255, 154, 22);
  myColors[6] = color(255, 53, 41); 

  fill(myColors[colorCounter]);

  ellipse(50, 50, 50, 50);

  println(colorCounter);

  // using % to wrap around and avoid NPE
  colorCounter = (colorCounter + 1) % myColors.length;
}
```

It will help to remember that `draw()` itself is an infinite loop so no need to add other loops inside of it. If you think you need a loop inside `draw()` then more often than not, you need to rethink your strategy because in most cases, you can just create a counter, like `colorCounter` in this example, and use it to control whatever it is you want to control within the `draw()` function.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying to my question. I get what you are saying. My lecturer explained it me in a similar way when I was finally able to see her. I tried making it work with a quick fix by adding a `void myColor` in my class with a `if` statement. I will have to re-look my code though. It still needs some work. Thanks once again.

Comment: @msmcd No problem. If the answer helped you then accept it by clicking on the green check mark. This way it shows that the question is resolved and has the required answer...and I get points which makes me want to keep on helping. :-)

Comment: Marked it!! Keep on helping poor coders like me. :-) Thanks @Nicolás